# Why my calculated TimeStamp is not exact (+32 or +16 seconds )?

Tags: objective-c, ios, timestamp, nsdate, nscalendar

I can't understand the result of my code, I need your help.

**For exemple, if current time is 5H00 AM, i want to get two timestamp when I call my method** :

```
[self getPeriodValues:@"day"];
```

- The timestamp of current day at 00H00.
- The timestamp of current time at 5h00 AM.

> For the first timestamp, I have the result, but with 32 more seconds !

**In my second exemple, if current date is 2011/12/30 at 5H00 AM, and i want two timestamp when I call my method** :

```
[self getPeriodValues:@"year"];
```

- The timestamp of current year with date 2011/01/01 at 00H00.
- The timestamp of current date and time : 2011/12/30 at 5H00 AM.

> For the first timestamp, I have the result, but with 16 more seconds !

**All my cases :**

- For @"day" i have 32 more seconds.
- For @"yesterday" i have 32 more seconds.
- For @"week" i have 32 more seconds.
- For @"month" i have 32 more seconds.
- For @"previousMonth" i have 32 more seconds.
- For @"year" i have 16 more seconds.
- For @"previousYear" i have 16 more seconds.

**here is the code of my method :**

```
-(void)getPeriodValues:(NSString*)period
{
log_debug("@@@@@ BackEnd - getPeriodValues @@@@@")

float startDateFloatTimeStamp;
float endDateFloatTimeStamp;

NSString * startDateStrNumericTimeStamp;
NSString * endDateStrNumericTimeStamp;

NSDateComponents *compsStart;
NSDateComponents *compsEnd;

NSDate * startDate;
NSDate * endDate;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date] ;
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
//NSInteger week = [dateComponents week];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];

log_debug (@"year : %ld", (long)year);
log_debug (@"month : %ld", (long)month);
log_debug (@"day : %ld", (long)day);
log_debug (@"hour : %ld", (long)hour);
log_debug (@"minute : %ld", (long)minute);
log_debug (@"second : %ld", (long)second);
log_debug (@"date : %ld", (long)[date timeIntervalSince1970]);

if ([period isEqualToString:@"day"]) {

    // start at 00h00m32s of current day to current time

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:month];
    [compsStart setDay:day];



    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:day];
    [compsEnd setHour:hour];
    [compsEnd setMinute:minute];
    [compsEnd setSecond:second];


} else if ([period isEqualToString:@"yesterday"]) {

    // Start yesterday at 00h00m32s, End today at 00h00m32s

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:month];
    [compsStart setDay:day-1];

    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:day];


} else if ([period isEqualToString:@"week"]) {

    // -7 days at 00h00m32s, End today at 00h00m32s

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:month];
    [compsStart setDay:day-7];

    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:day];

} else if ([period isEqualToString:@"month"]) {

    // ...

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:month];
    [compsStart setDay:1];

    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:day];
    [compsEnd setHour:hour];
    [compsEnd setMinute:minute];
    [compsEnd setSecond:second];

} else if ([period isEqualToString:@"previousMonth"]) {

    // ...

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:month-1];
    [compsStart setDay:1];

    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:1];

} else if ([period isEqualToString:@"year"]) {

    // du 01/01 de cette année à 00h00m16s, à aujourd'hui pour l'heure actuelle

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:1];
    [compsStart setDay:1];

    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:day];
    [compsEnd setHour:hour];
    [compsEnd setMinute:minute];
    [compsEnd setSecond:second];

} else if ([period isEqualToString:@"previousYear"]) {

    // ...

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year-1];
    [compsStart setMonth:1];
    [compsStart setDay:1];

    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:1];
    [compsEnd setDay:1];

} else {

    // ... same as day

    compsStart = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsStart setYear:year];
    [compsStart setMonth:month];
    [compsStart setDay:day];


    compsEnd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [compsEnd setYear:year];
    [compsEnd setMonth:month];
    [compsEnd setDay:day];
    [compsEnd setHour:hour];
    [compsEnd setMinute:minute];
    [compsEnd setSecond:second];

}

startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:compsStart];
startDateFloatTimeStamp = [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];

endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:compsEnd];
endDateFloatTimeStamp = [endDate timeIntervalSince1970];

startDateStrNumericTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i000",(int) floor(startDateFloatTimeStamp)];
endDateStrNumericTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i000",(int) floor(endDateFloatTimeStamp)];

log_debug(@"Start timestamp : %@",startDateStrNumericTimeStamp);
log_debug(@"End timestamp : %@",endDateStrNumericTimeStamp);

...
}
```

### Finally, why my method adds 32 or 16 seconds?

Edit for adding logs :

for @"day" case :

```
2012-01-02 09:09:43.855 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 82] year : 2012
2012-01-02 09:09:43.856 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 83] month : 1
2012-01-02 09:09:43.856 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 84] day : 2
2012-01-02 09:09:43.857 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 85] hour : 9
2012-01-02 09:09:43.857 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 86] minute : 9
2012-01-02 09:09:43.858 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 87] second : 43
2012-01-02 09:09:43.858 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 88] date : 1325491783
2012-01-02 09:09:43.859 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 232] Start timestamp : 1325458816000
2012-01-02 09:09:43.859 TestApp[33070:207] -[BEServiceWeather getPeriodValues:] [Line 233] End timestamp : 1325491840000
```

As we can see, for start day i have 1325458816000, when I should have: 1325458800000

Comment: I compiled this and I don't see any extra seconds when I print the startDate and endDate at the bottom of the method. Can you please provide a small example in unit test form with a failing assert?

Comment: @Gary, I provide you my logs for de day case.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, can you please provide the smallest possible test case with a failing assertion so I can reproduce it.